# How a REF102U precision voltage reference works?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, schematics, voltage-reference

I'm looking at the circuit schemes in which a precision voltage is used. I have never worked with them before.

I have read some literature and, obviously, its datasheet: [REF102U datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ref102.pdf?ts=1707132774070&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mouser.es%252F)

I didn't find information about pinout function but I've read something like:

- v+ is an input voltage: voltage that is desired to stabilize
- COM is a kind of ground of the circuit.
- OUT is the voltage stabilized at 10V
- Single-supply operation from 11.4V to 36V (I don't understand this spec)

As you can see this circuit doesn't use TRIM.

I would like to find some sense to the complet circuit, but first I think I need to know how the precision device works with COM, V+ and OUT with this configuration.

With the inverted input connection, op-amp is trying to strongly keep the FORCE+ at the op-amp output side. But I felt really strange with the op-amp there. I have not usually worked with voltage reference devices before, so I wasn't sure of anything.

The most strange for me is:

1. the input of this op-amp depending on the REF device output, and
2. the output of the op-amp is also the reference (ground) of the REF device.
3. Furthermore, the stablized output is the positive voltage rail of the op-amp. (mistake correction below)

NOTE1: FORCE+ is a line that comes from a connector. It is supposed to be one of the 4 wires used for resistor measure. I'm not completely sure, but I would say that  Force+ and Force- have too many votes to be the current source to connect the load.

[image: FORCE- is connected to the GND]

NOTE2: Circuit should be sawn with the relay under ON state.

Feel free to tell if I'm wrong.

3. So the op-amp output depends on an input voltage in the non inverter line. This input voltage comes from REF device and it depends on the op-amp output that connects to the ground device. (correction)

[image: voltage referent circuit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a precision current source for measuring resistance as in the [diagram from the dataheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ref102.pdf?ts=1707132774070&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mouser.es%252F), shown below.

The OUT pin provides a stable voltage for the current. The voltage across R125 (454k) is exactly the voltage from OUT to COM (10V). thus setting the load current to about 22μA.

The load voltage is set by the resistance under test. It is the load voltage that the op-amp transfers to the COM pin allowing the REF102 to "float" on the load voltage.

Knowing the current, and measuring the voltage allows the load resistance to be calculated with Ohm's law.

The relay connects the current source to the load. Leaving the relay contacts open when the current source is not used may not be a good idea, might be unstable. Better to connect the current source output to ground or V- as suggested in the image, when not in use.

> The most strange for me is:

> 1. the input of this op-amp depending on the REF device output, and

It doesn't. The configuration places 10V across R125, creating a constant current. The input voltage is determined by the load voltage responding to this current.

> 2. the output of the op-amp is also the reference of the REF device.

Yes, in a way. The voltage on the op-amp output is the load voltage, thus allowing the 10V of the REF102 to "float" above the load voltage in order to maintain the constant current.

> 3. Furthermore, the stablized output is the positive voltage rail of the op-amp.

No. The REF102 and the op-amp have a common 15V supply.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I was wrong with the Vout connection. I will edit that and I will update this third comment.

Comment: Please do not change the third comment. It makes my answer incorrect. Leave as is and make a correction at the end of the question. @Suvi_Eu

Comment: Thanks a lot. The picture you put has a great coincidence with this circuit. So it is a precision current source. It seems to be no doubt.

Answer (score 1):

> V+ [pin] is an input voltage: voltage that is desired to stabilize

Yes, and that voltage is relative to the COM pin.

> COM [pin] is a kind of ground of the circuit.

Correct.

> OUT [pin] is the voltage stabilized at 10V

Yes, and that voltage is relative to COM pin. Thus, if you measure COM to OUT, it's 10V, but COM to GND can be quite different.

> Single-supply operation from 11.4V to 36V (I don't understand this spec)

That means that the reference works like a voltage regulator with input range from 11.4V to 36V. If the input voltage is less than 11.4V, the output is not guaranteed to meet the specification anymore.

> I would like to find some sense to the complete circuit

The circuit doesn't make sense, for several reasons:

1. Using an LM358 to drive the COM pin of a precision reference turns said reference into a non-precision one. Compare the thermal stability of the REF102U output voltage vs. the thermal stability of LM358 offset. You need a much better op-amp, but even then I have no idea why you put that op-amp there in the first place...
2. When K5REL1 is open - position as shown - the circuit will either oscillate or get stuck in a state where the reference's COM-to-V+ voltage is out of operating range.

Are the FORCE lines supposed to provide the reference voltage, i.e. they should come from the reference circuit? Please edit the question (don't comment!) about what exactly is the circuit supposed to do once you finish it.

Answer (score 1):

They are probably trying to generate an excitation voltage (for some kind of bridge sensor or Kelvin resistor measurement) that is relative to a measured potential. The voltage at the non-inverting input of the LM358 will be close, but not exactly equal, to ground, maybe +/- a few hundred mV. That can compensate for resistance of relay contacts, lead wires and connectors.

The LM358 is an okay enough part for this because has a rather low drift and offset voltage relative to 10V. The REF102 is only accurate to +/-10mV for the cheap version and +/-2.5mV for the most expensive.

I can't quite suss out the circuit from the information provided, but that would be my expectation.